# Errno 2 - No such file or directory

Tags: python

I have a scrip that I use to scan through a directory and copy the content (actually I only want part of it...) of all files that containt a certain string into a new file.

```
import os
dr = "C:/Python34/Downloaded Files LALME/"; out = "C:/Python34/output_though_only.txt"; tag = ".txt"
files = os.listdir(dr)
for f in files:
  if f.endswith(tag):
    content = open(dr+"/"+f).readlines()
    all_lines = content   
    if ">though<" in all_lines:         
      open(out, "a+").write(all_lines)
infile = "C:/Python34/output_though_only.txt"
outfile = "C:/Python34/cleaned_output_though_only.txt"
delete_list = ['']
fin = open(infile)
fout = open(outfile, "a+")
for line in fin:
    for word in delete_list:
        line = line.replace(word, "")
    fout.write(line)
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

When I run it from the shell it returns the following error message:

```
C:\Python34>python LALME_script_though_extract_clean.txt -w
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LALME_script_though_extract_clean.txt", line 13, in <module>
    fin = open(infile)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Python34/output_tho
ugh_only.txt'
```

Of course, the file does not exist (yet), but the script is supposed to create it if it doesnt exist. This is a modified version of a code that I used for other strings and files and there it worked just fine.

Can anyone find what went wrong here ?

Edit: here is an older version of the script that works and was used for differenty files/directories.

```
import os
dr = "C:\Python34/tag/"; out = "C:\\Users/Yorishimo/Desktop/codes/LAEME/though/output_laeme_though/output_laeme_though.txt"; tag = ".tag"
files = os.listdir(dr)
for f in files:
  if f.endswith(tag):
    content = open(dr+"/"+f).readlines()
    all_lines = content
    needed_lines = content[21:27]       
    lines_totest = ("").join(all_lines)+"\n"
    final_lines = ("").join(needed_lines)+"\n"  
    if "$though/" in lines_totest:                       
      open(out, "a+").write(final_lines)
infile = "C:\\Users/Yorishimo/Desktop/codes/LAEME/though/output_laeme_though/output_laeme_though.txt"
outfile = "C:\\Users/Yorishimo/Desktop/codes/LAEME/though/output_laeme_though/cleaned_output_though_only.txt"
delete_list = ['</span></li><li><span class="list">', '<style type="text/css"> UL LI { list-style: none } </style><ul><li><span class="list">']
fin = open(infile)
fout = open(outfile, "a+")
for line in fin:
    for word in delete_list:
        line = line.replace(word, "")
    fout.write(line)
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Edit2:

Here is an example of a file that I am trying to have scanned for the string >though<:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>eLALME</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="Title" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Publisher" content="">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://archive.ling.ed.ac.uk/ihd/elalme_scripts/lib/css/elalme_actionstyle.css" type="text/css" target="taskarea">
</head>

<!-- MAIN CONTENT BELOW HERE -->

<body>
<style type="text/css">
  UL LI { list-style: none}
</style>
<p><span class="emphasis">LP 1</span></p><p>Dublin, Trinity College 154 (A.6.12). <span class="contr">ca.</span> 1400. MS in one hand. ff. 1r-105r: religious treatises. Analysis  from ff. 1r-41r, then scan. LP 1. Grid 478 332. Leicestershire.</p></p><table><tr><td>1</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">THE</span>: </td><td>y<sup>e</sup></td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">THESE</span>: </td><td>thes (theys) ((these))</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">THOSE</span>: </td><td>those (tho)</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">SHE</span>: </td><td>sche, she</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">HER</span>: </td><td>hir, hyr</td></tr><tr><td>6</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">IT</span>: </td><td>it</td></tr><tr><td>7</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">THEY</span>: </td><td>they ((thay, thei))</td></tr><tr><td>8</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">THEM</span>: </td><td>theym, them (thayme, theyme) ((yem, thaym, theme, yam))</td></tr><tr><td>9</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">THEIR</span>: </td><td>theyr (ther, y<span class="contr">er</span>) ((thayre, thayr, theyre, thare))</td></tr><tr><td>10</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">SUCH</span>: </td><td>suche ((syche))</td></tr><tr><td>11</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">WHICH</span>: </td><td>wiche, which (wyche, whiche, whyche) ((y<sup>e</sup>-wiche))</td></tr><tr><td>13</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">MANY</span>: </td><td>mony (many)</td></tr><tr><td>14</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">MAN</span>: </td><td>man, ma<span class="contr">n</span></td></tr><tr><td>15</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">ANY</span>: </td><td>any</td></tr><tr><td>16</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">MUCH</span>: </td><td>myche (mych, moche, meche, muche)</td></tr><tr><td>17</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">ARE</span>: </td><td>be (ar) ((are, er, byn))</td></tr><tr><td>18</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">WERE</span>: </td><td>were (ware) ((wher))</td></tr><tr><td>19</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">IS</span>: </td><td>is</td></tr><tr><td>21</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">WAS</span>: </td><td>was</td></tr><tr><td>22</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">SHALL</span> <span class="contr">sg</span>: </td><td>shal, schal, schall</td></tr><tr><td>22-30</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">SHALL</span> <span class="contr">pl</span>: </td><td>shall (shal) ((schall))</td></tr><tr><td>23</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">SHOULD</span> <span class="contr">sg</span>: </td><td>sholde (schulde) ((shulde))</td></tr><tr><td>23-30</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">SHOULD</span> <span class="contr">pl</span>: </td><td>sholde (schulde, shulde)</td></tr><tr><td>24</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">WILL</span> <span class="contr">sg</span>: </td><td>wyll</td></tr><tr><td>24-30</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">WILL</span> <span class="contr">pl</span>: </td><td>wyll</td></tr><tr><td>25</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">WOULD</span> <span class="contr">sg</span>: </td><td>wolde</td></tr><tr><td>26-30</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">TO</span> <span class="contr">prep</span> +V: </td><td>to</td></tr><tr><td>27</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">TO</span> <span class="contr">+inf</span> +C: </td><td>to</td></tr><tr><td>28</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">FROM</span>: </td><td>from (frome) ((fro))</td></tr><tr><td>29</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">AFTER</span>: </td><td>after</td></tr><tr><td>30</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">THEN</span>: </td><td>then ((than))</td></tr><tr><td>31</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">THAN</span>: </td><td>then (than) ((yen))</td></tr><tr><td>32</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">THOUGH</span>: </td><td>alof (yof) ((yoff))</td></tr><tr><td>33</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">IF</span>: </td><td>yff, yff-that, yf ((yf-y<sup>t</sup>, yff-y<sup>t</sup>, gyffe-y<sup>t</sup>))</td></tr><tr><td>34</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">AS</span>: </td><td>as</td></tr><tr><td>35</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">AS..AS</span>: </td><td>as+as</td></tr><tr><td>36</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">AGAINST</span>: </td><td>agance (agaynst, agayns, agayne)</td></tr><tr><td>39-20</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">SINCE</span> <span class="contr">conj</span>: </td><td>sythen-y<sup>t</sup>, syn</td></tr><tr><td>40</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">YET</span>: </td><td>&#0541;et ((&#0541;ett))</td></tr><tr><td>41</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">WHILE</span>: </td><td>whylys-y<sup>t</sup></td></tr><tr><td>42</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">STRENGTH</span>: </td><td>strenght ((strenghe))</td></tr><tr><td>42-20</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">STRENGTHEN</span> <span class="contr">vb</span>: </td><td>strenght</td></tr><tr><td>44</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">WH-</span>: </td><td>wh- ((w-))</td></tr><tr><td>46</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">NOT</span>: </td><td>not, nott</td></tr><tr><td>47</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">NOR</span>: </td><td>nor (ne)</td></tr><tr><td>48</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">OE</span>, <span class="smcap">ON</span> <span class="contr">&#0257;</span> (&#8216;a&#8217;, &#8216;o&#8217;): </td><td>o</td></tr><tr><td>49</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">WORLD</span>: </td><td>woorlde, worlde, warlde, world</td></tr><tr><td>50</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">THINK</span> <span class="contr">vb</span>: </td><td>thynke, thyngke</td></tr><tr><td>51</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">WORK</span> <span class="contr">sb</span>: </td><td>werke</td></tr><tr><td>51-10</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">WORK</span> <span class="contr">pres stem</span>: </td><td>werke</td></tr><tr><td>52</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">THERE</span>: </td><td>ther ((y<span class="contr">er</span>))</td></tr><tr><td>53</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">WHERE</span>: </td><td>wher-, where</td></tr><tr><td>54</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">MIGHT</span> <span class="contr">vb</span>: </td><td>myght</td></tr><tr><td>55</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">THROUGH</span>: </td><td>throughe (throghe) ((throught, through))</td></tr><tr><td>56</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">WHEN</span>: </td><td>when</td></tr><tr><td>57</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="contr">Sb pl</span>: </td><td>-ys (-s, -<span class="contr">es</span>) ((-es, -is))</td></tr><tr><td>58</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="contr">Pres part</span>: </td><td>-yng</td></tr><tr><td>59</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="contr">Vbl sb</span>: </td><td>-yng</td></tr><tr><td>61</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="contr">Pres 3sg</span>: </td><td>-ys (-yth, -eth, -<span class="contr">es</span>, -s)</td></tr><tr><td>62</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="contr">Pres pl</span>: </td><td>-th</td></tr><tr><td>65</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="contr">Weak ppl</span>: </td><td>-ed (-et) ((-yd))</td></tr><tr><td>66</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="contr">Str ppl</span>: </td><td>-en, -on, -yne</td></tr><tr><td>70-20</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">ABOUT</span> <span class="contr">pr</span>: </td><td>abowte</td></tr><tr><td>71-20</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">ABOVE</span> <span class="contr">pr</span>: </td><td>a-boue, abowe</td></tr><tr><td>73</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">AFTERWARDS</span>: </td><td>afterward</td></tr><tr><td>75</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">ALL</span>: </td><td>all, al</td></tr><tr><td>77</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">AMONG</span> <span class="contr">adv</span>: </td><td>emong</td></tr><tr><td>77-20</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">AMONG</span> <span class="contr">pr</span>: </td><td>emong</td></tr><tr><td>78-20</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">ANSWER</span> <span class="contr">vb</span>: </td><td>answer</td></tr><tr><td>80</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">ASK</span> <span class="contr">vb</span>: </td><td>aske</td></tr><tr><td>81</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">AT</span><span class="contr">+inf</span>: </td><td>at</td></tr><tr><td>83</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">AWAY</span>: </td><td>away</td></tr><tr><td>84-20</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">BE</span> <span class="contr">ppl</span>: </td><td>beyn (byn)</td></tr><tr><td>85-20</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">BEFORE</span> <span class="contr">adv-time</span>: </td><td>before, befor</td></tr><tr><td>85-31</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">BEFORE</span> <span class="contr">pr-place</span>: </td><td>be-fore, be-for</td></tr><tr><td>89</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">BETWEEN</span> <span class="contr">pr</span>: </td><td>betwene</td></tr><tr><td>93</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">BLESSED</span> <span class="contr">adj/ppl</span>: </td><td>blessyd (blessed) ((blyssed))</td></tr><tr><td>94</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">BOTH</span>: </td><td>bothe</td></tr><tr><td>96</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">BROTHER</span>: </td><td>broder (brother)</td></tr><tr><td>99</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">BUSY</span> <span class="contr">adj</span>: </td><td>besy ((busy))</td></tr><tr><td>99-20</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">BUSY</span> <span class="contr">vb</span>: </td><td>besy-, busy</td></tr><tr><td>100</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">BUT</span>: </td><td>bot (bott)</td></tr><tr><td>102</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">BY</span>: </td><td>by</td></tr><tr><td>103-30</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">CALLED</span> <span class="contr">ppl</span>: </td><td>called</td></tr><tr><td>104</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">CAME</span> <span class="contr">sg</span>: </td><td>came</td></tr><tr><td>105-20</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CAN <span class="contr">1/3sg</span>: </td><td>can</td></tr><tr><td>106</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">CAST</span> <span class="contr">vb</span>: </td><td>cast</td></tr><tr><td>108</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">CHURCH</span>: </td><td>churche</td></tr><tr><td>109</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">COULD</span> <span class="contr">1/3sg</span>: </td><td>cowthe</td></tr><tr><td>112</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">DAY</span>: </td><td>day</td></tr><tr><td>113</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">DEATH</span>: </td><td>dethe</td></tr><tr><td>114</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">DIE</span> <span class="contr">vb</span>: </td><td>dye</td></tr><tr><td>115-70</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">DID</span> <span class="contr">pl</span>: </td><td>dyd</td></tr><tr><td>116</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">DOWN</span>: </td><td>downe</td></tr><tr><td>119</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">EARTH</span>: </td><td>erthe</td></tr><tr><td>125</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">ENOUGH</span>: </td><td>enoughe</td></tr><tr><td>129</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">FAR</span>: </td><td>far</td></tr><tr><td>130</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">FATHER</span>: </td><td>fad<span class="contr">er</span>, fader</td></tr><tr><td>132</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">FELLOW</span>: </td><td>felou-</td></tr><tr><td>134</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">FIGHT</span> <span class="contr">pres</span>: </td><td>feght-</td></tr><tr><td>137</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">FIRE</span>: </td><td>fyer, fyre, fire</td></tr><tr><td>138</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">FIRST</span> <span class="contr">undiff</span>: </td><td>ferst, first</td></tr><tr><td>139</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">FIVE</span>: </td><td>fyve</td></tr><tr><td>139-20</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">FIFTH</span>: </td><td>feyfte</td></tr><tr><td>140</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">FLESH</span>: </td><td>fleshe, flesche</td></tr><tr><td>141</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">FOLLOW</span> <span class="contr">vb</span>: </td><td>folow, folo-</td></tr><tr><td>144-20</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">FOURTH</span>: </td><td>fawrte</td></tr><tr><td>146</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">FRIEND</span>: </td><td>frend-</td></tr><tr><td>147</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">FRUIT</span>: </td><td>frutt-</td></tr><tr><td>153</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">GIVE</span> <span class="contr">pres</span>: </td><td>gyue (gyff-)</td></tr><tr><td>155</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">GOOD</span>: </td><td>good, gud</td></tr><tr><td>157</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">GROW</span> <span class="contr">pres</span>: </td><td>groue (growe)</td></tr><tr><td>160</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">HAVE</span> <span class="contr">pres</span>: </td><td>haue</td></tr><tr><td>160-40</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">HAS</span> <span class="contr">3sg</span>: </td><td>hayth ((haythe, haith))</td></tr><tr><td>164</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">HEAVEN</span>: </td><td>hewyn</td></tr><tr><td>165</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">HEIGHT</span>: </td><td>heghte</td></tr><tr><td>166</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">HELL</span>: </td><td>hell</td></tr><tr><td>168</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">HIGH</span>: </td><td>hegh (heghe, hyghe)</td></tr><tr><td>168-20</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">HIGHER</span>: </td><td>hyer</td></tr><tr><td>171</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">HIM</span>: </td><td>hym</td></tr><tr><td>175</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">HOLY</span>: </td><td>holy</td></tr><tr><td>176</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">HOW</span>: </td><td>how (howe)</td></tr><tr><td>181</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">KNOW</span> <span class="contr">pres</span>: </td><td>knawe, knaw</td></tr><tr><td>185</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">LAW</span>: </td><td>lawe</td></tr><tr><td>187</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">LESS</span>: </td><td>lesse, leysse</td></tr><tr><td>190</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">LIFE</span>: </td><td>lyue</td></tr><tr><td>191</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">LITTLE</span>: </td><td>lyttyll (lyttyl)</td></tr><tr><td>192</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">LIVE</span> <span class="contr">vb</span>: </td><td>lyff-</td></tr><tr><td>194</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">LORD</span>: </td><td>lorde ((lord))</td></tr><tr><td>196</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">LOVE</span> <span class="contr">sb</span>: </td><td>loue (luffe, luff)</td></tr><tr><td>196-20</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">LOVE</span> <span class="contr">vb</span>: </td><td>loue</td></tr><tr><td>197</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">LOW</span>: </td><td>low-</td></tr><tr><td>199-10</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">MAY</span> <span class="contr">1/3sg</span>: </td><td>may</td></tr><tr><td>202</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">MOON</span>: </td><td>mone</td></tr><tr><td>203</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">MOTHER</span>: </td><td>mother, moder</td></tr><tr><td>204</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">MY</span> +C: </td><td>my</td></tr><tr><td>204-20</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">MY</span> <span class="contr">+h</span>: </td><td>my</td></tr><tr><td>205</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">NAME</span> <span class="contr">sb</span>: </td><td>name</td></tr><tr><td>210</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">NEITHER</span> <span class="contr">pron</span>: </td><td>nawther</td></tr><tr><td>211</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">NEITHER..NOR</span>: </td><td>nawther+ne, nother+nor, nawther+then</td></tr><tr><td>212</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">NEVER</span>: </td><td>neu<span class="contr">er</span></td></tr><tr><td>213</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">NEW</span>: </td><td>new-</td></tr><tr><td>214</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">NIGH</span>: </td><td>neyr, nere-</td></tr><tr><td>218</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">NOW</span>: </td><td>nowe, now</td></tr><tr><td>219</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">OLD</span>: </td><td>holde</td></tr><tr><td>220-20</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">ONE</span> <span class="contr">pron</span>: </td><td>one</td></tr><tr><td>221</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">OR</span>: </td><td>or</td></tr><tr><td>222</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">OTHER</span>: </td><td>other</td></tr><tr><td>224</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">OUR</span>: </td><td>oure</td></tr><tr><td>225</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">OUT</span>: </td><td>oute, out, owt</td></tr><tr><td>226</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">OWN</span> <span class="contr">adj</span>: </td><td>awne</td></tr><tr><td>227</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">PEOPLE</span>: </td><td>people, peopyll</td></tr><tr><td>228</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">POOR</span>: </td><td>pooer, poer, poore</td></tr><tr><td>229</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">PRAY</span> <span class="contr">vb</span>: </td><td>pray</td></tr><tr><td>235</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">SAY</span> <span class="contr">pres</span>: </td><td>say</td></tr><tr><td>235-21</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">SAYS</span> <span class="contr">3sg</span>: </td><td>sayth</td></tr><tr><td>235-30</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">SAY</span> <span class="contr">pl</span>: </td><td>sayth</td></tr><tr><td>235-40</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">SAID</span> <span class="contr">sg</span>: </td><td>sayde</td></tr><tr><td>235-60</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">SAID</span> <span class="contr">ppl</span>: </td><td>sayd</td></tr><tr><td>236</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">SEE</span> <span class="contr">vb</span>: </td><td>se</td></tr><tr><td>236-21</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">SEES</span> <span class="contr">3sg</span>: </td><td>seeth</td></tr><tr><td>237</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">SEEK</span> <span class="contr">pres</span>: </td><td>seke</td></tr><tr><td>238</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">SELF</span>: </td><td>selffe, selfe</td></tr><tr><td>242</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">SIN</span> <span class="contr">sb</span>: </td><td>synn-, syn ((syne))</td></tr><tr><td>242-30</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">SIN</span> <span class="contr">vb</span>: </td><td>synn-</td></tr><tr><td>243</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">SISTER</span>: </td><td>sust<span class="contr">er</span>, suster</td></tr><tr><td>244</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">SIX</span>: </td><td>sex</td></tr><tr><td>246</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">SOME</span>: </td><td>su<span class="contr">m</span>me ((sume))</td></tr><tr><td>248</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">SORROW</span> <span class="contr">sb</span>: </td><td>sorow, sorowe, sorousys<<span class="contr">pl</span>></td></tr><tr><td>249</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">SOUL</span>: </td><td>soule (saule)</td></tr><tr><td>249-20</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">SOULS</span>: </td><td>soules, saulis, sawl<span class="contr">es</span></td></tr><tr><td>254</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">STEAD</span>: </td><td>sted-</td></tr><tr><td>261</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">THOU</span>: </td><td>y<sup>u</sup></td></tr><tr><td>262</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">THEE</span>: </td><td>ye</td></tr><tr><td>263</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">THY</span> +C: </td><td>y<sup>i</sup></td></tr><tr><td>266</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">THOUSAND</span>: </td><td>thousande</td></tr><tr><td>267-20</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">THIRD</span>: </td><td>thryde, therde, threde</td></tr><tr><td>268</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">TOGETHER</span>: </td><td>to-gedder, to-gether</td></tr><tr><td>270</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">TRUE</span>: </td><td>true</td></tr><tr><td>273</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">TWELVE</span>: </td><td>twelue</td></tr><tr><td>275</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">TWO</span>: </td><td>too</td></tr><tr><td>278</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">UPON</span>: </td><td>apon (appon) ((vppon))</td></tr><tr><td>281</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">WELL</span> <span class="contr">adv</span>: </td><td>well ((wel))</td></tr><tr><td>282</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">WENT</span>: </td><td>went</td></tr><tr><td>285</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">WHETHER</span>: </td><td>whether (whed<span class="contr">er</span>, wether)</td></tr><tr><td>286</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">WHITHER</span>: </td><td>wheder</td></tr><tr><td>291</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">WHY</span>: </td><td>why</td></tr><tr><td>292-20</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">WIT</span> <span class="contr">1/3sg <span class="smcap">KNOW</span></span>: </td><td>wote</td></tr><tr><td>295</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">WITHOUT</span> <span class="contr">pr</span>: </td><td>w<sup>t</sup>-owte, w<sup>t</sup>-owt, w<sup>t</sup>-owtyn (w<sup>t</sup>-out)</td></tr><tr><td>297</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">WORSHIP</span> <span class="contr">sb</span>: </td><td>worschippe, worschip</td></tr><tr><td>298</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">YE</span>: </td><td>&#0541;e</td></tr><tr><td>299</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">YOU</span>: </td><td>you ((youe))</td></tr><tr><td>300</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">YOUR</span>: </td><td>you<span class="contr">r</span> (youre)</td></tr><tr><td>303</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">YOUNG</span>: </td><td>yong</td></tr><tr><td>304</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">-ALD</span>: </td><td>-old</td></tr><tr><td>306</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">-AND</span>: </td><td>-and (-ond)</td></tr><tr><td>307</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">-ANG</span>: </td><td>-ong ((-ang))</td></tr><tr><td>308</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">-ANK</span>: </td><td>-ank, -angk</td></tr><tr><td>309</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">-DOM</span>: </td><td>-dome, -dom</td></tr><tr><td>312</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">-ER</span>: </td><td>-er (-<span class="contr">er</span>) ((-ar))</td></tr><tr><td>313</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">-EST</span> <span class="contr">sup</span>: </td><td>-est</td></tr><tr><td>314</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">-FUL</span>: </td><td>-full</td></tr><tr><td>315</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">-HOOD</span>: </td><td>-hede, -hed</td></tr><tr><td>316</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">-LESS</span>: </td><td>-les</td></tr><tr><td>317</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">-LY</span>: </td><td>-ly</td></tr><tr><td>318</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">-NESS</span>: </td><td>-nes</td></tr><tr><td>319</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="smcap">-SHIP</span>: </td><td>-schippe, -schip</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Why have you used mixed forward slash and backward slash in the path name ?

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to open a file for reading that doesn't exist?

Comment: hm, not sure why I originally did that, but it never mattered with the other files or directories. I can change it of course, maybe it will make a difference, although I have no idead why. edit: ok, have updated the code in the question.

Comment: "Why would you expect to be able to open a file for reading that doesn't exist?" bc 'open(out, "a+").write(all_lines)' is supposed to create a new file if it doesn't exist. that always worked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `"<though>"` is supposed to be a line it won't be in readlines as there will be a newline to `"<though>"`  at the end. You need to add a newline or `str.rstrip` the lines in the list.

```
In [15]: l = [">though<\n"]

In [16]: ">though<" in l
Out[16]: False

In [17]: ">though<\n" in l
Out[17]: True
```

This will check for a match properly and use `glob` to find all the txt files in the directory also without storing all lines in a list:

```
dr = "C:\Python34/Downloaded Files LALME/"
out = "C:\\Python34/output_though_only.txt"
from glob import glob
tag = ".txt"
files = glob(dr+"*.txt")
with open(out, "w") as f:
    for fle in files:
        with open(fle) as f2:
            for line in f2:
                if line.rstrip() == ">though<":
                    f.seek(0)
                    f.writelines(f2)
                    break
```

And then reopen the file you after writing to it:

```
outfile = "C:\\Python34/cleaned_output_though_only.txt"
delete_list = ['']

with  open(out) as fin,open(outfile, "w") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        for word in delete_list:
            line = line.replace(word, "")
        fout.write(line)
```

But your delete list is empty so not sure exactly what that is doing.

Your code from your edit works as you are checking a string not a list:

```
n [20]: f = "foo"   
In [21]: l = ["foo\n"]    
In [22]: f in l
Out[22]: False    
In [23]: s = "".join(l)    
In [24]: s
Out[24]: 'foo\n'    
In [25]: f in s
Out[25]: True
```

You are checking for a substring in the edited code so even without the newline you will get a match, using a list you need to have an exact match which is what you have in your original code using `readlines` as you don't call `join` on as you do in the edited code.

So the big difference between both is one is checking for a substring in a string, the other is checking if an exact match is the list which fails because of the newline character.

Based on your new edit you are not checking for a line, you are checking for a substring an a case insensitive match so use:

```
`if ">though<" in line.lower()`
```

Comment: Isn't open(out, "a+").write(all_lines) supposed to create a new file ? It always did with the other files. ">though<" is supposed to be a string that is part of a line.

Comment: @Jonnecy, it can create a file but you don't create the file you are trying to read later, maybe the name is wrong in your code?

Comment: hm, I am not sure I understand you when you write that I do not create the file that I am trying to read later. as for the name of the file to be created and read, they are the same, the directories and file names were all copy-pasted.

Comment: Your if would never succeed so the file is never created

Comment: yes, that is the file I create and also the file it reports as non-existent, which does not make sense to me. the reason to the delete list is empty is simply because I have yet to figure out a string that I want deleted. you can refer to my older script in the edited question to see what it might look like. but right now that should not matter.

Comment: So why does my older script (see edit above) work and this one not ?

Comment: Because `"foo" in "foo\n"` is True `"foo" in ["foo\n"]` is not

Comment: ok, I think I am beginning to understand the problem;; if I want my new/edited script to work I will have to tell it to search for a substring in a string, right ? although I would rather have it search the entire textfile for an exact match.;/ the problem with the new files that I am trying to scan with the edited script is that the information I am interested in is somewhere in one (extremely) long line and the script will not work if I specify that line; maybe because internally there actually are tlines that I cannot see. I have added an example to the question above.

Comment: The code in my answer will scan the lines of each file and look for an exact match for `">though<"`, you don't need to use readlines or any other container. I edited my answer, if you are parsing html you might be better to use a htmll parse also

Comment: ok, I suppose that solves the problem in a more elegant way. with the code being as it is now cmd tells me that the name 'glob' is not defined:      C:\Python34>python LALME_new_script_though_extract_clean.txt -w                 Traceback (most recent call last):                                                File "LALME_new_script_though_extract_clean.txt", line 4, in <module>             files = glob(dr+"*.txt")                                                    NameError: name 'glob' is not defined                      What should I define it as ?

Comment: do you have `from glob import glob`?

Comment: oh, only had tried it with import glob. now that script does not return an error anymore. strangely enough though, the outfiles are all empty. which really shouldn't be the case as I know that this particular string is present in most of them;;

Comment: `print(files )` first and make sure we are getting a match

Comment: ok, I have added print ("match found") to the if, but apparently we are not getting a matchs;; which makes me wonder if this has anything to do with the internal structure of the files it is trying to read. where would I print the files first ?

Comment: ok, the current code until the `print(files)` looks like this: `from glob import glob
dr = "C:\Python34/Downloaded Files LALME/"
out = "C:\\Python34/output_though_only.txt"
tag = ".txt"
files = glob(dr+"*.txt")
print(files)`   It the proceeds to print all the files from 1-9999;but the created files are still empty. so for some reason the `if` is not succeeding.

Comment: which if are you using?

Comment: here's the rest except for the second process: `with open(out, "w") as f:
 for fle in files:
  with open(fle) as f2:
   for line in f2:
    if line.rstrip() == ">though<":
     print ("match found")
     f.seek(0)
     f.writelines(f2)
     break`

Comment: For your sample input you need the second if

Comment: without wanting to sound too stupid, what do you mean by "sample" and "second if" ? yes, I am quite a newb at this still;) but thanks for your patience!

Comment: sample -> file content in your question, second if -> `if ">though<" in line.lower()`